# Manifest Merger Failed - support:appcompat-v7:26.+

Tags: android, facebook, gradle, sdk, manifest

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31
>       is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-24:34 to override.

I am trying to make an App with a target SDK of 26.
The App needs the Facebook SDK (latest according to [Facebook SDK Versions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/downloads) of 4.25.0.

Volley is Version 1.0.0 ([Android Volley Dev Page](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html))

I can only from the error guess that some of these SDKs share libraries but one loads a different version to another...so I need to add some form of "load this and not this" like commands in my Gradle file? Or am I simply missing something?

The above error occurs with my Gradle Build files shown below.

Project Gradle Build:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App gradle build:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.johnny.fibre"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26

        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    //compile "com.android.support:support-core-utils:25.+"
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.johnny.fibre">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

        <activity android:name=".Home">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thank you for any help! I have been commenting and changing SDK versions and all sorts...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the issue with further forum browsing:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    //    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    //})
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'


}
```

The dependencies

```
com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

being added seem to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

`facebook sdk` is using  `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'` and `'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'` in its dependencies.

This error will be solved if you `exclude support-v4` from facebook dependency like below:

```
compile (‘com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.25.0’){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
```

or exclude it from `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'` in your dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I re-ordered the dependencies and added a couple of "newer" ones at the top that seem to have overwritten the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Exclude the dependencies from the libraries being trouble makers :-) Let's see an example:

```
implementation("com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:1.0.2") {
  exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

You can be more specific adding the module you want to exclude, as well:

```
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue change the following compile files in build.gradle in app folder. Now i am using these compile files.

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.+'
```

before change i am using these files

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

Just change the Version of compile files.Use "26.+" instead of "26.0.0-alpha1"

Thanks