# Error on com.android.support:appcompat-v7, when try add facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, android-appcompat

I wanna install login facebook sdk in my Android app, already i import the SDK to the project app, the problem i get is with appcompat

the problem is i dont know what need to do to fix the problem, i dont know how to implement the suggestion android studio give

below show the details of my code

this is my :
build.gradle (Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
     compileSdkVersion 26
     buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
     defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.perugiftart.facebooksdk"
         minSdkVersion 15
         targetSdkVersion 26
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
         testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }
     buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
     } }

 dependencies {
     compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
     androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2',
 {
         exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
     })
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'

     compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
     testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
     compile project(':facebook-android-sdk-4.25.0')
     compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'

     compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'


 }
```

the error appear here:

> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'

this is the message error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>
> > Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-alpha1) from
> >     [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1]
> >     AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38       is also present at
> >     [com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-31
> >     value=(25.3.1).       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to
> >      element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:41 to override.

im not sure how can fix this error on my code, please help

Comment: please add language about what are you trying to achieve, what problems did u face and what is your exact problem !!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manifest Merger Failed - support:appcompat-v7:26.+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397697/manifest-merger-failed-supportappcompat-v726)